# Order and color of bars in ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very annoying problem with a stacked bar plot created using `ggplot2`. 
There are a couple of similar questions previously asked but after going through the example code I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I would like to make the graph so that the bars are stacked in the following order based on their `Biogeographic.affinity`: (Top to Bottom= Bassian,Widespread,Torresian, and Eyrean). The colors to the bars should be: (Bassian=drakgrey, Widespread=lightgrey, Torresian=white, and Eyrean=black).

This is what the dataset looks like:

```
  biogeo
       Site Biogeographic.affinity Rank Number.of.species Total.Species    Percent
    1     A                Bassian    1                 1           121  0.8264463
    2     A                 Eyrean    4                39           121 32.2314050
    3     A              Torresian    3                62           121 51.2396694
    4     A             Widespread    2                19           121 15.7024793
    5    DD                Bassian    1                 1           128  0.7812500
    6    DD                 Eyrean    4                46           128 35.9375000
    7    DD              Torresian    3                63           128 49.2187500
    8    DD             Widespread    2                18           128 14.0625000
    9   E_W                Bassian    1                 1           136  0.7352941
    10  E_W                 Eyrean    4                54           136 39.7058824
    11  E_W              Torresian    3                65           136 47.7941176
    12  E_W             Widespread    2                16           136 11.7647059
    13   KS                Bassian    1                 2           145  1.3793103
    14   KS                 Eyrean    4                63           145 43.4482759
    15   KS              Torresian    3                62           145 42.7586207
    16   KS             Widespread    2                18           145 12.4137931
    17 Z_Ka                Bassian    1                 1           110  0.9090909
    18 Z_Ka                 Eyrean    4                64           110 58.1818182
    19 Z_Ka              Torresian    3                31           110 28.1818182
    20 Z_Ka             Widespread    2                14           110 12.7272727
```

This is the code I have written so far (including some of my failed attempts to correct the problem).

```
 ggplot(data=biogeo, aes(x=Site, y=Percent, fill=Biogeographic.affinity)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black")+ 
  scale_fill_grey() + ylab("Percent") + xlab("Location") +       
  theme_bw()+ theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

This gives the basic graph but the colors and order are still wrong. To correct the order I tried, but that did not change anything (FRUSTRATED)!:

```
newone <- transform(biogeo, Biogeographic.affinity  = factor(Biogeographic.affinity ), Rank = factor(Rank, levels = 1:4))
```

As for color changing I have tried and seems to work but it all looks like the order is still wrong!

```
cols<- c("Bassian"="darkgrey","Widespread"="lightgrey", "Torresian"="white", "Eyrean"="black") #designates the colors of the bars 
ggplot(data=newone, aes(x=Site, y=Percent, fill=Biogeographic.affinity)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) + ylab("Percent") + xlab("Location") +       
  theme_bw()+ theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

please help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The order that bars are drawn (bottom to top) in a stacked barplot in ggplot2 is based on the ordering of the factor which defines the groups. So the Biogeographic.affinity factor must be reordered. Generally we use `reorder`(if we want to order the factor according to a continuous levels) but here I will just create a new ordered factor similar to what you tried to do.

```
 biogeo <- transform(biogeo, 
                Biog.aff.ord  = factor(
                     Biogeographic.affinity ,
                     levels=c( 'Bassian','Widespread','Torresian', 'Eyrean'),
                     ordered =TRUE))
```

Now if you fill your barplot using **Biog.aff.ord** rather than the original factor and overriding the default grouping order by defining **aes_group_order** as Biog.aff.ord order you get the expected result:

```
cols <- c(Bassian="darkgrey",Widespread="lightgrey", 
            Torresian="white", Eyrean="black") 
ggplot(data=biogeo, aes(x=Site, y=Percent,
       order=Biog.aff.ord)) +   ##!! aes_group_order
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black",
        aes(fill=Biog.aff.ord)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

[image]

Comment: @IDelToro the order of levels? Why?

Comment: In the current version of ggplot2, ordering factor levels no longer works in the specific case of bar plots with `stat = "identity"` and `position = "stack"` or `position = "fill"`. (Also, I believe the `order` aesthetic has gone away.) Instead, you must now actually sort the data frame itself into the "correct" order. See [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1593).